# How to set "split_on_numerics" to false in ElasticSearch mapping using ElasticPress? (for proper SKU search in WooCommerce)

Tags: plugins, search

I've been using ElasticSearch v7.10 installed on the same server that I have a website in WordPress with WooCommerce, that is connected using the plugin ElasticPress v4.0.

I am trying to modify mapping but so far with no success. This because when we search for a SKU, although the corresponding item comes up in first most of the times, it also shows other results and sometimes it's not even on the first place the exact match.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Forced SKU to be indexed
- Forced variations SKUs to be indexed
- Used Debug Bar with ElasticPress Debug to check query
- Google searched for days for ways to modify ElasticSearch mapping and tried multiple examples
- Asked for help in Github for ElasticPress (which they answered this is not a bug or issue to solve there and pointed to paid consultancy)

And here's the code that supposedly should work and it's not:

```
function configMapping($mapping){
    // bail early if $mapping is missing or not array
    if ( ! isset( $mapping ) || ! is_array( $mapping ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // ensure we have filters and is array
    if (! isset( $mapping['settings']['analysis']['filter'] )
        || ! is_array( $mapping['settings']['analysis']['filter'] )) {
        return false;
    }

    // ensure we have analyzers and is array
    if (! isset( $mapping['settings']['analysis']['analyzer']['default']['filter'] )
        || ! is_array( $mapping['settings']['analysis']['analyzer']['default']['filter'] )) {
        return false;
    }

    // define the custom filter
    $mapping['settings']['analysis']['filter']['my_custom_word_delimiter_filter'] = array(
        'type'                  => 'word_delimiter',
        'split_on_case_change'  => false,
        'split_on_numerics'     => false
    );

    // tell the analyzer to use our newly created filter
    $mapping['settings']['analysis']['analyzer']['default']['filter'][] = 'my_custom_word_delimiter_filter';
    return $mapping;
}
add_filter('ep_config_mapping', 'configMapping', 10, 1);
```

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm just out of ideas! :(

Comment: Unfortunately your journey must continue - neither WooCommerce nor ElasticSearch are within the scope of our Stack. You might try a more general WordPress/web dev community :(

Comment: @bosco I've actually found and solved this problem myself and commented bellow the result. Since I am using ElasticPress (a WordPress plugin) to connect to ElasticSearch, I thought I could apply this question here. Anyway, problem solved and I just wanted to share it with anyone else that could have this problem as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was tough, but here is the solution for this!

First, you will need to use SSH to access the server where you have ElasticSearch installed.

After that, you will want to perform these commands:

- This one will first close your index, only then you can perform changes:

  curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/YOUR-INDEX/_close?pretty
- This one will put the filter for "word_delimiter":

  curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/YOUR-INDEX/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
  {
  "settings": {
  "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
  "my_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": [ "word_delimiter" ]
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }'
- Then we put the filters we want, like so:

  curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/aYOUR-INDEX/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
  {
  "settings": {
  "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
  "my_analyzer": {
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": [ "my_custom_word_delimiter_filter" ]
  }
  },
  "filter": {
  "my_custom_word_delimiter_filter": {
  "type": "word_delimiter",
  "type_table": [ "- => ALPHA" ],
  "split_on_case_change": false,
  "split_on_numerics": false,
  "stem_english_possessive": true
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }'
- Last but not least, you will want to open your index again, so here we go:

  curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/YOUR-INDEX/_open?pretty

I had to perform all these steps because my index was already created, otherwise it would be basically like we see on the [example page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html).

Hope this helps future visitors. :)